# Keepass: Update in binary file foo.kdbx results in conflicts

Tags: password, keepass, owncloud-client

I use keepass to store some password. The folder containing the file foo.kdbx is shared via owncloud.

I see that a file called foo_conflict-20160810-075402.kdbx was created.

I exported the foo.kdbx and foo_conflict-20160810-075402.kdbx to the xml format and compared both using the tool `meld`.

I see a lot of changes on fields with these names:

- LastAccessTime
- UsageCount
- LastTopVisibleEntry

Is there a way to tell keepass (I use the desktop and the android version) to not save these unimportant meta data changes?

I want reading a value from keepass to be read-only. Otherwise I need to resolve the conflict which costs too much time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with owncloud or how it handles file conflicts, but there are a few Keepass options you can change to try to get the functionality you want.

If you want Keepass read-only and always have it open on the source machine, you can try using Keepass's native lock files option under `Tools → Options → Advanced → File Input/Output Connections → Use database lock files`. I would assume that would provide a similar function, though it probably isn't the most secure way to do things.

You can also try the `Do not ask whether to synchronize or overwrite; force synchronization` option (in the same section) to ensure your database updates are always synced, which (I believe) *should* prevent most if not all conflicts.

For the actual data storage, while you can hide or show details like "Last Modification Time", I'm pretty sure you can't actually remove the variable or tell Keepass not to track that information.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I never open keepass twice at one moment. That is not the problem. The problem is that keepass modifies the database although I don't change anything. The field "Last Modification Time" is ok, since if I modify the db, then this additional change does not hurt. In 90% of all cases I use keepass only readonly. In this case the file should not be changed.

Comment: Oh I see where I misread. That really is a strange way for Keepass to handle that. It looks like you can tweak their visibility through [the configuration file](http://keepass.info/help/v2_dev/customize.html) but I'm not sure that would fix your problem. There's a [whole](https://sourceforge.net/p/keepass/bugs/1172/) [discussion](https://sourceforge.net/p/keepass/feature-requests/169/) in the dev forums about it.